# R, Change distance between axis tick marks and tick mark labels

Tags: r, graphics

In the following example, I plot a custom tick mark at .95 (edited to make labels horizontal as per Thomas' suggestion):

```
d = matrix(runif(40), ncol=4)
colnames(d) = c('a','b','c','d')

barplot(
    d,
    beside=T, 
    col=c('#CD4E3C', '#816DC3','#569340', '#A87929'), 
    ylim=c(0,1), 
    cex.axis=.80,
    main= 'Title',
    las=1

)

abline(h= 1:10/10, col = 'lightgray', lty=3)
axis(side=2, at=c(.95), cex.axis=.75, tck=-.01, las=1)
abline(h= .95, col = '#000000', lty=3)
```

Which gives:

[image]

My custom label is too close to the regular label (which I also need), and I'd like to bring the label closer to the tick mark. I looked through

```
help(par)
```

How might a bring that label closer to the axis?

EDIT: 
Making the tick mark labels horizontal helped, but I'd still like to indent the label for .95 to reflect the shortened tick mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution is to put `las=2` in both your `barplot()` and `axis()` calls to make labels horizontal and they'll be clearer.

EDIT: Use `mtext` instead of `axis`:

`mtext("0.95",2,.5,at=.95,las=2,cex=.75)`

Comment: Thanks! mtext works nicely in conjunction with an axis call with labels=FALSE to still get the tick mark. I used las=1 to for all labels to be set to horizontal (las=2 flips the x axis labels sideways when used with barplot)